# A bug in Questions? [In Stackoverflow only - Not in Meta]

Tags: discussion, status-bydesign, voting

I recently noticed in the questions that the left upvote/downvote counter remains static even though you scroll down.  Great!!! (**It's not static in Meta**)

[image]

But, when I visit my own questions, the counter on the left does not become static:

[image]

Well, it is not a big issue to cause me headache, but was curious if this is something I am only experiencing personally or something that needs to be reported.

Answer (score 6):

It's by design.

The voting arrows are only sticky when you can vote, and as you can't vote on your own questions they aren't sticky.

[A/B testing the sticky vote controls - give your feedback, please](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/258048/a-b-testing-the-sticky-vote-controls-give-your-feedback-please)

Comment: That's what I wrote in a comment initially, and though this is what the OP meant is it intentional that it doesn't move on your own questions? Does it move on answers to your own questions? (Problem with AB testing is that you have no choice if you get added to the test group so I can't test it...)

Comment: @Ben I see what you mean, but the voting arrows should move on answers to your questions. I don't know for sure, because I've never got the sticky arrows yet.